# MySQL does not return all the values in a CSV

Tags: java, mysql, excel, csv, import

I have imported a CSV to a MySQL table.
The CSV contains employee details and has 687 entries.
MySQL imports all the 687 entries into the database.

When I execute the statement `INSERT INTO copyemployee SELECT * FROM employee where country='India'` only 87 entries are being inserted, while I have 92 entries in the CSV.

I have tried changing the country but I'm facing the same issue.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Could you do a: SELECT * FROM employee where country='India' and see how many results you get?

Comment: You have to try to construct some mechanism that allows us to replicate the problem. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Have you check what value are rejected in this, is there a logic explaining the problem ? Is there any constraint on copyemployee ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that the issue is that CSV file has India written in different ways. Try to normalize your CSV file removing white spaces, special characters and etc, this way you are going to have a more consistent result.

Step 1: Let's first make sure all the results from the CSV file were imported to the database:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM employee;
```

(**EDIT**: Result: 687)

Step 2: Try this to check it how many results you got:

```
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE country='India';
```

(**EDIT**: Result 87)

Step 3: Or you could also use (Suggested by someone else in the comments, but it was deleted):

```
SELECT count(1), country from employee group by country;
```

With that you will see a list of different countries you have. You are probably going to find India more than one time, written in a different way. Maybe with a space after or something like that.

**EDIT after your shared your CSV**: You should have 5496 (8 * 687) commas in your CSV file. But you have 5555. That means that you have commas in the middle of other entries. So your CSV file is inconsistent using commas, you could try using ; instead. That explain why you have Designations on your contry entry.

Example of a wrong line: Sameer,,Khawaja,SK3533,Sameer.Khawaja@sailpoint.com,"Manager, Technical Support",India,Maharashtra,Pune.

That puts his Designation as Manager, and his country as Technical Support.

Another solution is simply garantee that you don't have any commas in your entries.

Comment: You are probably correct - if you were to provide a sql solution to check, I would probably upvote you

Comment: @ScaryWombat I actually had put the SQL to check it on a comments to the question, but you are right. I edited the question to suggest it here also. Thank you for the constructive comment.

Comment: @BrenoQ : inline 'SELECT * FROM employee WHERE country='India';  returns 87 results instead of 92.' while inline 'SELECT DISTINCT country FROM employee;' returns designations of employees too.

Here's the schema on SQL Fiddle
[link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d1a16/1)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: so maybe other possibilities exist like `country='india'` or `country='India    '` - you will have to find out whether the data exists, or it failed to insert.

Comment: @VishalSurya how many results: SELECT count(*) FROM employee returns? 687? Let's first make sure every row of the CSV file was inserted.

Comment: @ScaryWombat: I have used data validation on excel for the Country field.
So it allows me to choose from a defined set of countries, which I believe reduces the chance of spelling mistakes.

When I filter according to country Excel shows "91 out of 687 records found" on the bottom right corner, however, the number of entries in the sheet itself is 177.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: @BrenoQ Yes, select * from employee returns 687 entries.

Comment: @VishalSurya  Ok, so now we are sure that everything was imported, the only problem is that some of them are not finding India the way you are expecting it. Do you mind posting the result of step 3? I changed it now to a new one. Its edited in my answer.

Comment: @VishalSurya If the Designations are showing up, is because your are adding designations as countries. The problem is most liketly to be because you are using a CVS separated by commas. And probably some of your entries have commas in the middle of the fields. You have 687 entries and each entry should have only 8 commas which is 5496. But you actually have 5555 commas. That will make your CSV inconsistent. You could try importing a CSV with ; instead of ,

Comment: @VishalSurya check an example of a wrong line in the end of my answer.

Comment: @VishalSurya another solution is just ensure that you don't have any commas in your entries.